# Flowfram doesn't transition from one flowframe to another after updating flowfram package

Tags: natbib, flowfram

Today I updated my TeX distribution due to another issue, from a TL13 distro around september 2013, to a TL14 distro (most recent).

After I updated, `flowfram` ignores one of my `\newflowframe` declarations, causing `flowfram` to continue using the mimicked three column layout from earlier declarations. This only seems to happen with my bibliography, using `natbib`.

The following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{flowfram}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}
\usepackage[square, numbers, sort]{natbib}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newflowframe[1,2]{\dimexpr\textwidth/3-2\columnsep/3}{\textheight}{0pt}{0pt}
\newflowframe[1,2]{\dimexpr\textwidth/3-2\columnsep/3}{\textheight}{\dimexpr\textwidth/3-2\columnsep/3+\columnsep}{0pt}
\newflowframe[1,2]{\dimexpr\textwidth/3-2\columnsep/3}{\textheight}{\dimexpr2\textwidth/3-4\columnsep/3+2\columnsep}{0pt}

\newflowframe[3]{\textwidth}{\textheight}{0pt}{0pt}% or \newflowframe*[>2]{\textwidth}{\textheight}{0pt}{0pt}

\begin{document}
\tolerance=4000

When considering the EoL phase, it's desirable to initially consider the shortest possible cycles of energy, namely reuse, and in closing consider the largest possible cycle, which would be recycling. Case studies in the UK have mapped the waste problem to comprise as much as 15 million discarded mobile phones each year\citep{website:fonebak}. Large scale reuse brings problems, however. A variety of problems arise when considering reuse of mobile phones, such as their low residual value, their small size or the complexity of channels through which they are distributed\citep{ends1997}. Furthermore, a case study reveals most private customers prefer to give mobile phones away\citep{ends2000}, making the previously mentioned legislation of EPR a considerably hard task to achieve. Currently, manufacturers, retails and mobile phone operators. Figures from Foneback\citep{website:fonebak} suggest this to be inadequate. One suggestion would be to promote horizontal collaboration between competitors\citep{canning2006}. Coercion among competitors puts forward a problem in the same fashion as that of renewable energy in the industry sector, namely the problem of managing and putting constraints on collective goods: to promote a change, everybody has to invest into renewable energy. So even though competitors would want to make a change, that change hits a threshhold. A consequence of such constraints is a hit to the economy as we know it now, which inherently forces a gradual change. One recommendation would be to develop a mathematical model, determining how steep this gradual change would have to be to compensate for the need for change currently. Removing a such barrier would be vital to success of reuse practices as we know them now.

\lipsum[1-8]
\cleardoublepage
\small
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
\bibliography{paper}
\end{document}
```

With some bib entries so it actually typesets a bibliography:

```
@misc{website:fonebak,
  title = {Fonebak - Facts},
  url = {http://www.fonebak.com/},
  note = {(accessed 28-9-2014)},
  year = {2014}
}

@REPORT{ends1997,
    author = {Environmental Data Services (ENDS)},
    title = {Take back schemes launched for mobile phones},
    issue = {264},
    year = {1997},
    month = {January}
}

@REPORT{ends2000,
    author = {Environmental Data Services (ENDS)},
    title = {Compliance scheme envisaged for mobile phone recycling},
    issue = {304},
    year = {2000},
    month = {May}
}

@ARTICLE{canning2006,
    author = {Louise Canning},
    title = {Rethinking market connections: mobile phone recovery, reuse and recycling in the {UK}},
    journal = {Journal of Business \& Industrial Marketing},
    volume = {21},
    issue = {5},
    year = {2006},
    pages = {320--329}
}
```

Both of these files can also be obtained through the following link: ([zip package](https://mega.co.nz/#!zU43zTCS!5ua__6w83Gybv_WPt8BMtQGa46WlZ09EPdnymFcAjaY))

The earlier declared single column layout flowframe (`\newflowframe[3]{\textwidth}{\textheight}{0pt}{0pt}% or \newflowframe*[>2]{\textwidth}{\textheight}{0pt}{0pt}`) is (seemingly) ignored. Instead, it continues to typeset a three column layout:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/Y2ZKF8G.png]

Previously, the output simply obeyed the layout I declared, something like this (from the main document - I obviously can't mimic the result anymore):

[image: http://i.imgur.com/8UWfRU8.png?1]

Comment: The frames aren't being ignored. If you insert `\lipsum[1-2]` immediately before `\bibliography`, you'll see the text fills `\textwidth`. (Also, if you use the `draft` option to `flowfram` you'll see the frame layout on page 3.) Something has changed the line width for bibliography but I don't know why this has happened. I'll investigate further.

Comment: I think it may be related to a bug fix in v1.16. MWE: `\documentclass{article} \usepackage{flowfram} \usepackage{lipsum} \twocolumn[1,2] \onecolumn[>2] \begin{document} \lipsum[1-10] \clearpage \lipsum[1] \begin{itemize} \item \lipsum*[2] \end{itemize} \end{document}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an unwanted side-effect of a bug fix that was needed to fixed an issue when list environments spanned two flow frames of different widths. Here's a minimal example that illustrates the problem:

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage{flowfram}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\twocolumn[1,2]
\onecolumn[>2]

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-10]
\clearpage
\lipsum[1]

\begin{itemize}
 \item \lipsum*[2]
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

The problem only affects the list environments and since the bibliography is in one of these environments, that's the cause of the problem in your document. You can fix it by inserting `\linewidth\columnwidth` before the list environment. For example:

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage{flowfram}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\twocolumn[1,2]
\onecolumn[>2]

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-10]
\clearpage
\lipsum[1]

\linewidth\columnwidth

\begin{itemize}
 \item \lipsum*[2]
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

For your example document put `\linewidth\columnwidth` in front of `\bibliography`.

**Edit**: I've fixed this bug and uploaded version 1.17 to CTAN. It may take a few days to get into the distributions.